# thunderbird how to apply a folder view to other folders (like evolution)

Tags: view, directory, thunderbird

How does one save a 'view' in thunderbird and then have that applied to other folders (nested and not nested) ? a bit like evolution and outlook?

For the life of me, i can't find this in my version:

Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.1.10) Gecko/20100528 Thunderbird/3.0.5

thanks,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A bit late but nevertheless - there is a button (the rightmost columns header) that allows you to select which column to show / hide. In the end there is an option of 'Apply columns to ...'. Select the desired folder and voila!

Answer (score 0):

But that action does not transfer all VIEW properties, SORT property is transfered wrongly and it does not transfer at all the (NON)THREADED property.

Looks like it only trnsfers columns order and columns visible property.